# c# MVC3 Need help making a Controller method more DRY

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dry

I have a model class:

```
public class Service
{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string description { get; set; }

    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public decimal cost { get; set; }
    public decimal manDay { get; set; }
    public decimal FTE{ get; set; }

}
```

I also have a simple controller that will loop through the entire `Services` database table and will return a JSON table of one of the `Service` attributes depending on an input parameter:

```
public JsonResult _columns(int attributeCode)
{
    IQueryable<Service> services = db.Services.AsQueryable();

    MyJSONContainer jcontainer = new MyJSONContainer();

    switch(attributeCode)
    {
        case 0: 
            foreach(Service s in services) 
                jcontainer.addEntry(s.description, s.price);
            return Json(jcontainer);
        case 1: 
            foreach(Service s in services) 
                jcontainer.addEntry(s.description, s.cost);
            return Json(jcontainer);
        case 2: 
            foreach(Service s in services) 
                jcontainer.addEntry(s.description, s.manDay);
            return Json(jcontainer);
        default:
            foreach(Service s in services) 
                jcontainer.addEntry(s.description, s.FTE);
            return Json(jcontainer);   
    }
}
```

Now this code works well, but is not very DRY, especially as I will probably be adding more complexity to the code within the `foreach` loop in the future.

I would be interested in knowing how somebody with more expertise in DRY design patterns would write this function.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, they where very informative, I wish I could accept both as the correct answer. I have gone for @Raphaël-Althaus 's solution in the end as I think it would be easyer to understand by my coleuges as it involves less code and classes. However If anyone is reading this question with a similar issue, I strongly recommend you consider both answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a method in your class (or as an extension method in an helper class, with minor changes, if you don't wanna have "attributeCode" logic in your model class)

```
public decimal GetValueFor(int attributeCode) {
  switch(attributeCode) {
    case 0 : return price;
    case 1 : return cost;
    case 2 : return manDay;
    default: return FTE;
  }
}
```

then in your action

```
public JsonResult _columns(int attributeCode)
{
    var services = db.Services.AsQueryable();
    var jcontainer = new MyJSONContainer();

    foreach(var service in services) 
        jcontainer.addEntry(service.description, service.GetValueFor(attributeCode));

    return Json(jcontainer);

}
```

Comment: I'm glad you suggested that: I thought of doing that myself, but disregarded it as it amounts to having the `switch` within a `for` loop which I assumed (perhaps erroneously) to be far less efficient. Wouldn't this have a severe impact on performance? Especially if we are talking about 500+ entries in the DB?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll give it a try. And you would consider it a better design practice?

Comment: @Chopo87 well, hard to say "from scratch". If I had to do this, I would probably work rather on the "db.Services" part, and return just what I would need from the db... But the important think is, first, to make things readable, before thinking to performances. And that solution is certainly easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to expand on it in the future, then I would move the tasks into their own class.

First a general builder:

```
static class JsonResultBuilder
{   
    public static JsonResult Build(Database db, int attributeCode)
    {
        var propertyRetriever = JsonServicePropertyRetrievers.Get(attributeCode);

        IQueryable<Service> services = db.Services.AsQueryable();
        MyJSONContainer jcontainer = new MyJSONContainer();

        foreach(Service s in services)
            jcontainer.addEntry(s.Description, propertyRetriever(s));

        return Json(jcontainer);
    }
}
```

Then a separate class which you can easily add more property retrievers with:

```
static class JsonServicePropertyRetrievers
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, Func<Service, object>> ServicePropertyRetrievers = new Dictionary<int, Func<Service, object>>();
    private static readonly Func<Service, object> DefaultServicePropertyRetriever;

    static JsonResultBuilder()
    {
        DefaultServicePropertyRetriever = s => s.FTE;

        Register(0, s => s.price);
        Register(1, s => s.cost);
        Register(2, s => s.manDay);
    }

    public static void Register(int attributeCode, Func<Service, object> propertyRetriever)
    {
        ServicePropertyRetrievers[attributeCode] = propertyRetriever;
    }

    public static Func<Service, object> Get(int attributeCode)
    {
        Func<Service, object> propertyRetriever;
        if (!ServicePropertyRetrievers.TryGetValue(attributeCode, out propertyRetriever))
            propertyRetriever = DefaultServicePropertyRetriever;

        return propertyRetriever;
    }
}
```

This way there is no increasingly large switch statement. If you wish to dynamically add support for codes, you can easily use the `JsonServicePropertyRetrievers.Register` method. If you don't want to expose support for that, just make the method private. If you want to remove retrieval methods, you can add a `Remove` method.

I'd also recommend implementing an `enum` for your `attributeCode` if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I am curious how do you think performance will compare with @Raphaël-Althaus and my simple switch approach

Comment: It will likely be negligible compared to the overhead of hitting the database services. The _logical flow_ of any of these solutions will be very fast compared to each other (unless you are doing tens of thousands to millions of iterations per second, which I doubt is the case). Choose a solution that is the most testable, readable, maintainable, and extensible for you. Unless you have _measurable bottlenecks_, don't worry about optimizing as it will likely be [premature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). Focus on correctness _then_ optimize where _needed_.